# Calling a template function from a C file

Tags: c++, c, templates, template-function

I know that templates are not defined in C. However in my case, i have an API written in C++, which is used by an application written in C. I wish to add a template function in the API. The function is defined as follows in abc.cpp:

```
template<typename T> T function_name(T param1){
  ...
  ...
  return val;
}
```

the declaration in abc.hpp as follows:

```
template<typename T> T function_name(T);
```

and this function is called from xyz.c as:

```
int a ,b = 5;
a = function_name(b);
```

However, it shows the following error in both abc.cpp and abc.hpp:

```
 error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘<’ token
 template<typename T>
```

Even using extern "C" doesn't help(leads to error: template with C linkage). My doubt is, is it even possible to call this template function in such a way? If yes, how can this be achieved? Thank you.

Comment: The "error: template with C linkage" error is the hint you should be taking; it is not intended that it can be done with C calling C++ directly.  You'd have to know the mangled C++ name for an instantiation of the template function, and then the C code would call that.  That ties you to a particular C++ compiler (possibly even a specific version of the compiler).  The correct way to do it is `extern "C" int template_int_function_name(int param1) { return function_name(param1); }` and then the C calls `template_int_function_name()`. This gives you a C-callable wrapper for the template function.

Comment: The application may suddenly turn out to be written in C++ ;-) (if you decide to compile it with a C++ compiler). Chances are that you need minor adaptions, in particular if the code follows unwind's advice to not cast the return value of `malloc()`, but the edits are usually fairly minor.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Re "call template function directly through mangled name": The instantiation may not even exist (and lead to a link-time error) if no C++ code, i.e. here no code inside the library, calls the function with an int argument. If the function is a recent addition to a library that is rather likely.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: Yes; that's another possible defect with trying to call the mangled name.  Unlikely, but possible.  And just another nail in the coffin of a thoroughly dead idea — it is absolutely not the correct way to go.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler So that would mean, i will have to write a wrapper function for every possible return type, right? Here, i am writing just the API, that is to be used by applications written in C/C++, so i guess i will have to go by peter's solution.

Comment: Yes, you would need wrappers for every type that needs to be used by the C code.  It would be sensible not to use the template functions from C.  Rewriting those functions in C++ may be better, but idiomatic modern C++ is very different from C.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks. That was really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mix C and C++ already (and therefore must have taken care of the possible issues), another solution is to continue developing the *application* in C++.  That way new code can use all the nice features of the C++ library, like templates ;-), overloaded functions etc., and has access to C++'s standard library which can greatly enhance productivity.

I don't see principal obstacles to using C++ for new source files in the application; whether it's easily possible and worthwhile to switch existing C files to C++ upon edits is another question.

Answer (score 9):

No, of course not, template functions don't exist in C and you can't parse a template declaration with a C compiler.

You're going to have to add a C wrapper on the C++ side for the `int` instance of the template, and call that (e.g. something like `function_int()`).

Answer (score 0):

Since C does not support templates, you can consider to use Type-Generic Functions - a macro-based method of defining generic expressions.

If this is not a case, I suggest to stay with C++ compiler.

Comment: If you mean `_Generic`, it is not a macro-based solution but is a full operator in the language — it is described in the standard in section §6.5.1.1 **Generic selection**, which is part of section §6.5.1 **Primary expressions**.  Section 6.10 describes the preprocessor.